# Representing strike lines in rose diagrams

Tags: geology, structural-geology

How can you best represent strike data on a rose diagram? Is it okay to plot only the strike?

Answer (score 4):

> **How can you best represent strike data on a rose diagram?**

In [rose diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_rose) lines are represented and strike is a line so I don't see the problem: *diagrams don't bite!*

---

> **Is it okay to plot only the strike?**

Why not, if the rose diagram helps in the description and there is not a technical impediment?

[image]

[Source](https://www.usna.edu/Users/oceano/pguth/md_help/html/rose_diagram.htm)

But... what about representing extra data besides the set of strikes?

[image]

[Source](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Rose-diagrams-The-rose-diagrams-for-the-average-strike-of-the-reactivated-fracture-zones_fig3_312070347)

You are not going to be the first one plotting lines in a circular diagram of frequencies, but you should consider before publishing: *does the diagram add sense to my report?*

Comment: Thank you very much